# Scrapy - How to write to a custom FEED_URI

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and I would like write backups of the HTML that s3. I found that by using the following, I could write a particular scrape's html:

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINE = {
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.S3FilesStore': 1
}

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['S3_MAIN_KEY']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY= os.environ['S3_MAIN_SECRET']

FEED_FORMAT = "json"
FEED_URI=f's3://bucket_name/%(name)s/%(today)s.html'
```

And then in my scraper file:

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield {'body': str(response.body, 'utf-8')}
```

However, I would like to write to a key that includes the url as a subfolder, for example:

```
FEED_URI=f's3://bucket_name/%(name)s/%(url)s/%(today)s.html'
```

How can I dynamically grab the url for the FEED_URI. I'm assuming that in

```
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://www.example.com',
            'http://www.example_1.com',
            'http://www.example_2.com',
        ]
```

I have multiple urls. Also, is there anyway to write the raw HTML file, not nested in JSON? Thanks.

Comment: Scrapy does not allow dynamic FEED_URL. You will have to write your own method inside Pipeline,

Answer (score 0):

[Feed exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html) are not meant to export to a different file per item.

For that, write an [item pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) instead.